# AWS S3 - Redirect - edited host URL is not changed in the redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

**Problem**

I want to forward a call to my URL in Route53 `myurl.com` to an other website let's say `google.com` and followed AWS described steps.
When it comes to S3 configuration "[Redirecting requests for a bucket's website endpoint to another host](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AmazonS3/latest/dev/how-to-page-redirect.html)".

- I set it up as described: S3 -> Properties -> Static website hosting -> Redirect requests for an object -> Host = `bing.com`.
- Now my URL got's created `http://myurl.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` and I got forwarded to `bing.com`.
- But when I changed it I still got forwarded to `bing.com` and not to `google.com` what I configured as host.

**What I tried**

If I delete my bucket "myurl.com" and create a new one with the new host `google.com` I still got forwarded to `bing.com`.

**Question**

- Takes it some time to push this change and is this described somewhere?
- Is it a bug?
- Do I miss something?

Comment: you would like to do whenever `myurl.com` hit it should redirect to `bing.com` ?

Comment: right and myurl.com is the hosted url I have in my Route53 with A record pointing to the S3 "myurl.com"

Comment: if you are hosted in Route53 then should not worried about S3 endpoint URL. as per your point its redirecting `bing.com` this is what exactly you need ?

Comment: no I want to get redirected to google because this is configured in S3 as host. But I still get redirected to bing.

Comment: after creation of new bucket have you map to hosted zone record ?

Comment: yes but the issue is already with the S3 so with the created link by the S3 ´http://myurl.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com´

Comment: You have to keep domain name entry and S3 bucket name same then it will automatically pick while editing hosted zone record.

Comment: yes I have it the same both "myurl.com". I follwed the AWS instructions.

Comment: only option to see your configuration. Whatever you are mentioned seem like good only.

Comment: After a day the link from S3 was correct and changed the forwarding (so also route53 forwarding works now). Anyway, thanks for your help.